# Retrieve the value of multiple cells and opening files in Excell

Tags: excel, notepad++

I am trying to copy the content of 2 separate cells together with a command to launch the Notepad++ to open 2 files for visual comparison in Excell 2016 on Windows 10.

e.g. cell [1,A] - `C:\Comparison\file1.txt`
cell [1,B] - `C:\Comparison\file2.txt`

And would like cell [1,C] to include the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" C:\Comparison\file1.txt C:\Comparison\file2.txt
```

I have tried the line in cell [1,C] below without success:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,A)) = INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,b))
```

I would also like the ability to run the command in cell [1,C], to launch Notepad++ and open the 2 files in Excell instead of copy-paste to the Windows Search field before pressing  to achieve the same thing.

There are many rows of files that require comparisons.

Comment: Why run Notepad to run excel? Why not just open Excel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cell C1 needs to contain a formula. Something like

```
="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe "&A1&" "&B1
```

If A1 and B1 need to be enclosed in quotes then use

```
="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe """&A1&""" """&B1&""""
```

Comment: Your initial suggestion worked beautifully. Thanks a lot. It would be fantastic if you can explain what each of the double quotes and the ampersand at the beginning and back means since I am a novice to Excel formulas. How did the double quotes achieve "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" (include the full path - space between Program and Files) so Notepad++.exe could be called? Also, is there a way to run the value/outcome of C1 formula by launching Notepad++ and open these files in Excel if possible? Thanks again.

Comment: This is not a viable solution as it takes a long long time (~20-30min) to update 100+ rows. One might as well write a script to achieve the same objective.

Comment: I do not understand your second comment. What is taking 20 to 30 minutes? Copying the formula from C1 into the other cells in column C takes almost no time and in my experience Excel is very fast at calculating formula.

Comment: Agree with your rationale and the Excel 365 workbook is less than 200KB yet it would take a good 20min to copy the contents from cell A1 and B1 to C1. The status is processing x percentages. I am running a Lenovo T16 laptop with 16GB of RAM. It is not worth investigating since I have used scripting to get much much faster results. The sluggishness may be due to the amount of applications being opened...